# Login and keep session cookie open with wget

Tags: bash, cookies, session-cookies, wget

Based on checking the man pages and examples online, i use the following to goto a page with a login screen, passing in the credentials.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --post-data 'userID=user1&password=password1' https://x.y.com/service.php

wget  --no-check-certificate --load-cookies cookies.txt https://x.y.com/service.php
```

The service.php login page's returned file shows that the fields for user and password above are correct (userID and password).

```
   <div style="width: 435px;margin-bottom: 20px;height: 29px;">
            <label style="line-height: 30px;float:left" for="usermail">User ID:</label>
            <input style="float:right;font-size: 9pt;width: 350px;margin-right: 0px;" type="text" name="userID" required>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 435px;margin-bottom: 10px;height: 29px;">
            <label style="line-height: 30px;float:left" for="password">Password:</label>
            <input style="float:right;font-size: 9pt;width: 350px;margin-right: 0px;" type="password" name="password" required>
        </div>
```

However after running the wget with load-cookies, we still get the page returned with the login page. I'm sure it's something small i'm doing incorrectly, but am not sure.

Comment: It probably needs some more fields.  Try logging in using a web browser and take a look at the full HTTP Request. What is the complete POST payload? You will need to modify that and send it